# Websphere server name equivalent on Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, websphere

I have this on websphere,

```
import com.ibm.websphere.runtime.ServerName;  

ServerName.getDisplayName();
```

What is the equivalent of this server instance name on Tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe tomcat servers are 'named'. You could try to get product name and version using the following code as described here - [Get Java application server name and version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7441048/3701228). Check if this is good enough for you.

```
String str1 = getServletContext().getServerInfo();
```